# Function such that $f(\frac{1}{n}) = n/(n + 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove something about functions that satisfy

$$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{n + 1}.$$

Obviously, one thing that we can do is

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x} $$

because we can write $\frac{n}{n + 1} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$.

But is there any other function that can satisfy this property? I think the answer is no, but how can I show it? Thanks

Comment: If you are not asking for any special property of $f$ (continuity etc) then you can define $f$ quite arbitrarily when $x$ is not of the type $\frac 1 n$.

Comment: Domain of function?

Comment: Domain $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I also need $f$ analytic if it matters

Comment: Ok if $f$ is analytic, how can I show it is unique ?

Comment: @joseph The fact that a function is analytic is *always* relevant, because being analytic is such an absurdly strong restriction.

Comment: if there were another function that has the same values, it would be identical to the one you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic in $\{|x| <1\}$ and $f(\frac 1 n)=\frac n {n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ then $f(x)-\frac 1 {1+x}$ is also analytic in the same disc and it vanishes at the points $\frac 1 n$. Hence it must be identically $0$ so $f(x)=\frac 1 {1+x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: why must $f(x) - \frac{1}{1 + x}$ be analytic too in the same interval?

Comment: @joseph Because it is the difference of two analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

If there is another function $f^*(x)$ that satisfies the requirements, then it shall be equal to the $f(x)=1/(1+x)$ that you already found plus an additional function (say $g(x)$), which shall have zeros at $x=1/n$.

The set $\{1/n\}$ has an accumulation point at $0$, and an analytic function cannot have accumulation point for its zeros.
I leave the conclusion to you.

Comment: i don't know why it needs to have zero at $x = 1/n$

Comment: @joseph: your function $f(x)=1/(1+x)$ already "interpolates" the $f(1/n)$. Then a new function $f^*(x)$ would be equal to $f(x)+g(x)$, where $g(1/n)$ shall be null.